# How to unit test each exception without mocking

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm trying to do a unit test for the following code. I don't know how to get 100% coverage as, without mocking which I'm really not a fan of, I don't know how to pass through all the If statements.
Many thanks

```
public static int Log(Exception ex)
{

    if (config_info.EnableRayGun)
    {
        try
        {
            dynamic c = new RaygunClient { UserInfo = new Mindscape.Raygun4Net.Messages.RaygunIdentifierMessage(GetUsername()) };

            c.Send(ex);
        }
        catch
        {
            //Swallow the exception. Oh the irony.
        }

    }


    if ((config_info.GelfPublisherEnabled))
    {

        try
        {
            dynamic publisher = new GelfPublisher(config_info.GelfPublisherIP, config_info.GelfPublisherPort);
            dynamic msg = new GelfMessage
            {
                FullMessage = ex.Message,
                TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow
            };
            msg.Add("error", ex);
            publisher.Publish(msg);


        }
        catch
        {
        }

    }

    if ((config_info.EnableApplicationInsights))
    {
        dynamic ai = new TelemetryClient();
        ai.TrackException(ex);
    }

    return DoLog(ex);
}
```

Comment: First of don´t use `dynamic` if you know the type (personally I´d suggest to not use it at all, unless you really *have* to). Second mocking is needed when you want to test a member without testing its dependencies, that is any member of other classes e.g. So you should do this. However your code is nearly un-mockable, as you´re introducing your dependencies directly within your class instead of injecting them. Last: I´m unsure wbout what you actually want to test here. If your methods were called? Or if they do right thing? What is *right*?

Comment: Btw.: How should any test-code get your exceptions when you´re swallowing them? That´s a really bad idea.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I'm looking to get 100% code coverage on this, if possible, what would be your approach

Comment: First you shouldn´t strive towards 100% coverage as this is unrealistic on most systems, try to figure the relevant branches in your code that are likely to be executed in a normal use-case. Apart from this you can´t expect your test to magically detect the exceptions your swallowing in your code. The fact that you´re saying you´re not a fan of mocking makes me believe you don´t know much about it, so you should find out what it actually means and how it relates to testing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `MSTest` framework for your unit testing then you can use `ExpectedExceptionAttribute` like

```
[ExpectedException(typeof(System.Exception))]
public boid MyTest()
{
  //test code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how would i use this to go into each IF??

Comment: @K---, sorry didn't get you ... you don't go in each `IF` ... rather just call your method under test and if your test case returns a exception then `expectedexception` will pass it if the thrown exception type matches with definition